# How to find which program is executing given program?

Tags: process, i3, debugging, strace

Is there way how to find out which program is executing my script?

I'm runnig I3 as my window manager and I want to use `sxkhd` to bynd keys instead of i3config but something keep replacing my sxkhd bynds, so I want to trace what is it.
Maybe I could use `strace` but I haven't figured out how.

Thanks for answers

EDIT:
turned out I didn't kill my old `sxkhd` processes so they were guilty for executing my script
butt I am still curious how could I trace these executions

Comment: Are you on Linux?

Comment: Yes, Fedora running I3-gaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you can get a PID of the parent process from `$PPID` variable or /proc/pid/status. Parent process is not always a calling process in
case of daemons for examples but it usually is. That being said, you
can convert every program into a wrapper that will first log PID of
its parent process to a file and then execute an original binary.  I
don't use sxkhd but as you use X11 let's use xeyes as an
example. Create `xeyes` script with the following contents and make it executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

printf "PPID: %d\n" "$PPID" >> /tmp/XEYES_RUN
xeyes.orig "$@"
```

Now rename an original xeyes binary to xeyes.orig:

```
sudo mv "$(command -v xeyes)" "$(dirname $(command -v xeyes))"/xeyes.orig
```

Replace original `xeyes` with a script wrapper:

```
sudo cp ./xeyes "$(dirname $(command -v xeyes.orig))"
```

Call `xeyes` normally:

```
xeyes
```

Now every time you run xeyes PID of its parent process will be
appended to /tmp/XEYES_RUN.  If you start it from the command line it
will be PID of your shell, for example /bin/bash.

Comment: Very nice solution. Got little confused with all $ on the command line, but still understood the point.

Answer (score 0):

From the shell, on Linux:

```
readlink "/proc/$PPID/exe"
```

In any standard shell, the `$PPID` variable refers to the parent process. In C, you can get it with `getppid()`. Most languages have a way to retrieve it (eg. `getppid` in perl, `os.getppid` in python, etc).

Once you got the PID of the parent process, mapping it to an executable is bound to be system specific. `ps` will tell you the process name or the command line arguments, but those are **not reliable**, as they (generally) don't include the full path and can be modified by the process itself, or by any other process running as the same user.

On Linux, the executable of a process is pointed to by `/proc/<pid>/exe`. That's a "magic" symlink: even if the original executable was removed or renamed, you still can read it (eg. to copy elsewhere) or execute it again.